# How to access Topaz Signature Pad ActiveX object through javascript?

Tags: javascript, activex, electronic-signature, topaz-signatures

We are using the [Topaz Systems](http://www.topazsystems.com) signature pad device for recording electronic signatures on documents.

Here is the company provided demo for javascript usage:

> Javascript-based HTML Internet Signature demo [download](http://topazsystems.com/software/download/web/html_javascript_demo.zip)

The signature pad is added to the page through an `<OBJECT />` element.

```
 <OBJECT classid=clsid:69A40DA3-4D42-11D0-86B0-0000C025864A height=75
         id=SigPlus1 name=SigPlus1
         style="HEIGHT: 90px; WIDTH: 300px; LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px; border: 1px solid #000; margin-top:10px; " VIEWASTEXT>
     <PARAM NAME="_Version" VALUE="131095">
     <PARAM NAME="_ExtentX" VALUE="4842">
     <PARAM NAME="_ExtentY" VALUE="1323">
     <PARAM NAME="_StockProps" VALUE="0">
 </OBJECT>
```

The documentation for performing actions on the object in javascript references VBScript and calls the object by id only.

```
<script language="javascript">  

    function OnClear() {
       SigPlus1.ClearTablet();
    }

    function OnCancel() {
       SigPlus1.TabletState = 0;
    }

</script>
```

I found that this approach fails to find the actual object in the DOM with all associated methods and attributes. Calling these functions results in:

> SigPlus1 is undefined

OR

> SigPlus1.ClearTablet() is not a function

How can I get the actual object in the javascript functions in order to call its methods and set its properties?

I have tried using prototype and jQuery to select the object in the DOM.

```
var vsig = $('SigPlus1');  // prototype
var vsig = $('#SigPlus1'); // jQuery
var vsig = document.form.SigPlus1; // document
```

None of which give the actual object required.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Roberjo, I tried running your code but in my case the SigData is undefined. When I click the sign button, there no signature appearing in the object tag. I tried testing in my DemoOCX.exe if my e-signature is working but it works fine there. Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question and be sure to include your code related to how the Sig Pad is being initialized.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the actual object by using `document.getElementById(id);`

So this code ended up working:

```
var vSig = document.getElementById('SigPlus1');
```

I hope this saves someone else from having to search for this answer!

Answer (score 2):

Once you have vSig initialized, you can call the associated functions and access the properties of the signature. For example the "Save Signature' button onclick should fire something like this:

```
function OnSaveSignature() {
    var vSig = document.getElementById('SigPlus1');
    if(vSig.NumberOfTabletPoints == 0){ // No signature data (Did not sign yet)
        alert("No Signature Found!");
    } else {
        vSig.TabletState = 0;  // Turn off sig tablet 
        vSig.SigCompressionMode = 1;  // Set compression mode
        mySaveSigFunction(vSig.SigString);  // Save sig data
    }  // Done!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it working by ignoring the "script" function for OnSign() and replacing the onclick="OnSign()" in my button with:

```
<INPUT id="SignBtn" name="SignBtn" type="button" value="Sign" onclick="javascript:SigPlus1.TabletState = 1;">
```

(ie I just took the javascript code from the  section and used it directly instead of as a function.

I suppose my question is in relation to your answer, what do I do with the variable vSig once it is set by getElementbyId? As I'd prefer to leave the code within my script section.

Thanks